# Адаптивная верстка блоков с соединёнными блоками (как в таблице colspan rowspan)

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

Стоит задача сверстать блоки для **мобильной**, **планшетной** и **десктопной** версии сайта. Есть 6 блоков, и в каждой из версий они расположены по разному:

[image: Пример расположения блоков]

В **десктопной** версии уже 3, а не 2 колонки – это отметает использование `table`. Также в **десктопной** версии есть соединение вертикальных и горизонтальных блоков – то есть и `flex` уже не получится использовать.

Как такое можно сверстать?
Можно ли обойтись чистым `CSS` или нужно ещё подключать `JS`?

Comment: Смотри grid верстку! https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В вашем случае идеально подойдет **[CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)**:

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
.grid {
  height: 400px;
  color: #fff;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "a a b c"
                       "d e r c";
}
.block1 {
  grid-area: a;
  background: red;
}
.block2 {
  background: green;
}
.block3 {
  grid-area: c;
  background: blue;
}
.block4 {
  background: purple;
}
.block5 {
  background: black;
}
.block6 {
  background: grey;
}

@media (max-width: 720px) {
    .grid {
      grid-template-areas: "a a"
                           "b d"
                           "e c"
                           "r c";
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
   <div class="grid__item block1">Grid Item 1</div>
   <div class="grid__item block2">Grid Item 2</div>
   <div class="grid__item block3">Grid Item 3</div>
   <div class="grid__item block4">Grid Item 4</div>
   <div class="grid__item block5">Grid Item 5</div>
   <div class="grid__item block6">Grid Item 6</div>
</div>
```